# Returning between functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Is there a way to return `user_input_1` and `user_input_2` into the `function_3` without using `temp_var_1` and `temp_var_2` and insert it directly?

What is the correct way of doing it?

```
def function_1():
    user_input_1 = input("\nInput the first word: ")
    return user_input_1

def function_2():
    user_input_2 = input("\nInput the second word: ")
    return user_input_2

def function_3(user_input_1,user_input_2):
    user_input_total = user_input_1 + user_input_2
    print(user_input_total)

def main():
    temp_var_1 = function_1()
    temp_var_2 = function_2()
    function_3(variable_1,variable_2)

main()
```

This is not working.

```
def function_1():
    user_input_1 = input("\nInput the first word: ")
    return user_input_1

def function_2():
    user_input_2 = input("\nInput the second word: ")
    return user_input_2

def function_3(user_input_1,user_input_2):
    user_input_total = user_input_1 + user_input_2
    print(user_input_total)

def main():
    function_1()
    function_2()
    function_3(function_1,function_2)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
In [885]: def function_3(): 
     ...:     print(function_1() + function_2()) 
     ...:   
  
In [883]: def main(): 
     ...:     function_3() 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [884]: main()                                                                                                                                                                                            

Input the first word: Stack

Input the second word: Overflow
StackOverflow
```

Or by your method, you need to change your `main()` function to below:

```
def function_3(user_input_1,user_input_2):
    user_input_total = user_input_1 + user_input_2
    print(user_input_total)

def main():
    function_3(function_1(),function_2())

main()
```

Comment: What would be best practice to use? If you had to review code for someone or had to work with someone, which version would you prefer that person is using?

Comment: It's always best to break code into reusable functions. I would use the way that you used in your question, using temp_variables to store functions values and then returning the output.

Answer (score 1):

Note: There are various ways to do that:

I hope this resolves your problem:

```
def function_1():
    user_input_1 = input("\nInput the first word: ")
    return user_input_1

def function_2():
    user_input_2 = input("\nInput the second word: ")
    return user_input_2

# Call function 1 & 2 from function 3 itself.
def function_3():
    print(function_1() + function_2())

# Call Main Func
def main():
    function_3()

main()
```